# Script to Propercase all Records in Sales Cloud

Tags: javascript, lightning

I just became our Sales Cloud Admin and need to clean up our mess of data. I want to go in and run a script to propercase all the records so they have unified capitalization. Is it possible for a script to run through all existing records and update capitalization?

Comment: Are you trying to just change the way the UI displays the data, or actually touch the database? Your tags indicate the former, but your question body seems to indicate the latter.

Comment: I am fine with either way as to why the tags are a bit generic. Just looking for some insights on what could be done. I would probably prefer a more light weight UI solution.

Comment: I don't think a UI solution would be as lightweight as you think. That said, you will be far more likely to receive useful answers if you **[edit]** this post to be much more specific about what type of data changes you are hoping for. Including examples would also help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I, personally, would not attempt to implement data cleanup via a UI layer. There's too many aspects of the UI that cannot be overridden or that are code-expensive to override for this to be a sustainable and effective solution.

On the back-end side, there's a ton of options that you can key to your code tolerance and your budget. Additionally, you need to consider the distinction between fixing your existing data and applying validation and invariants to your new, incoming data. On the latter, I'd simply point you to the various Trailhead modules covering data quality, deduplication, and validation rules, as the topic's really too broad to even summarize here.

But as for fixing your existing data... Well, the below has two purposes. One is to share some examples of viable solutions, of which there are many; the other is to try to emphasize the level of complexity that *could* be involved here. Exactly how tricky this turns out to be will depend hugely on your data volume and the specific configuration of your Salesforce org.

**Batch Class**

Write an Apex batch class to perform your data transformation, prepare unit tests for that batch class, and do a full test run in a full copy sandbox.

Once you're fully satisfied with the class's operation, move it to Production and kick it off with Anonymous Apex.

Running destructive-change scripts across your entire database is, to say the least, dangerous. Test thoroughly.

Downsides:

- It's code, and you won't be visually inspecting changes that are made as a sanity check.
- Edge cases are really easy to miss.
- The last modified date and last modified by user will reflect the run time of your batch and its running user.
- You may need to tune batch size to tolerate the weight of your existing code base.

  - Apex offers fewer amenities for text processing than many general-purpose programming languages.

**Data Loader (Manual ETL)**

Pull all the affected records down using Data Loader or another ETL tool, and process them however you please - I'd typically use LibreOffice on a CSV like this due to Excel's propensity for wrecking international text. For a small, relatively simple org, I would probably use this approach.

Then push them all back up with Data Loader.

Upside is that you get to see exactly what's going to be changed before it's changed, and you can visually observe edge cases or issues.

Downsides:

- Slow, manual.
- Like Batch, updates the timestamps on everything.
- Still have to be aware of batch size issues.

**External Data Cleaning Tool**

You can apply a third-party data cleaning tool to perform bulk data changes and cleaning. I have used DemandTools for this general type of process (though not capitalization specifically) in the past, but it's not the only player in this space. You might also look at applying one of the open-source ETL tools, like Talend or Pentaho - I am less familiar with their capabilities myself.

Upsides include speed, direct control, and not needing to write code.

Downsides:

- May or may not have direct visibility into operation, depending on the tool selected.
- Can be pricy if a commercial solution is selected.
- Same caveats on batch size as above solutions.

**Off-Salesforce Scripting**

Because it falls within my personal wheelhouse, I would probably script the entire process with a Python script talking to the Salesforce REST API. It wouldn't run as fast as a batch process (probably), but it would be fast enough unless the data volume is sufficient to demand the Bulk API, which would also be an option.

You could do this in most general-purpose programming languages based on your familiarity and specific requirements (Python, JavaScript, Ruby, Java... C if you *really* want to). The main upside is it gives you total control and allows you to use your local storage and RAM to circumvent some, but not all, of the limits on on-platform processing.

Downsides:

- Requires different technical expertise than simple Apex Batch script.
- Harder to unit test than Batch Apex.
- Same caveats as all code-based solutions.